# In Hangfire, how to call method using RecurringJob

Tags: .net-core, hangfire

I got simple method with defination defined in a interface. I am trying to call this method from Startup.cs using RecurringJob but getting exception. This is very simple test method.

### Interface

```
 public interface IEziDataLoader
{
    Task TestMe();
}
```

### class

```
public async Task TestMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method called from Hangfire");
        
    }
```

### Startup.cs

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IEziDataLoader>($"TestMe", x => x.TestMe());
```

### error

```
 cannot resolve AddOrUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer;

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("hello", () => Console.WriteLine("hello World"), "* * * * *");

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IDataLoader>("TestMethod", x=>x.TestMe(), "* * * * *");
```